# Protractor Object [object Object] has no method 'then'

Tags: node.js, protractor, fedora

I've just installed protractor on my fedora work station. My tests work fine on Windows 7 and OS X, but on fedora I get this error:

> Message:
>       Failed: Object [object Object] has no method 'then'   Stack:
>       Error: Failed: Object [object Object] has no method 'then'
>           at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:102:16
>           at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
>           at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
>           at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)

Obviously the difference between the work stations is huge. Even node runs in different versions (0.10.36 on fedora). But maybe someone has the same problems?

Comment: You’re gonna need to show more than this error… Are you using the same protractor version on both machines? If you want the same behavior on both machines, you’re gonna have to use the same versions of everything.

Comment: Show your test and on which line does it fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are running Protractor 2.0 on your workstation, and 1.x on your other machines. [Protractor 2.0 has a breaking change](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/1d8f14eb7e3fd7c8607ef1ffa2d6c0b29cc802b1/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) that removes `element.then`. You'll need to update your tests to address this change.

Comment: This is a guess, but quite an educated one. I think this is it though we need to see the code to be sure about it.

Comment: I hit exactly this problem when migrating from 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: thanks a lot, completely right! since my package.json is very unspecific on the protractor version, the fresh setup uses protractor 2.0.